# Android annotations REST send image

Tags: android, android-annotations

I use android annotations to communicate with the server. In one of the api calls I need to send some text data and an image, say, from gallery.

```
@Post("/items/addItem.php")
String addItem(Protocol protocol);
```

How do I attach a MultipartForm with an image along with the post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the right Spring converter : [FormHttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#FormHttpMessageConverter).

However, this converter only accepts [MultiValueMap](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) as method parameter. Please have a look at these two issues: [#652](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/652) and [#660](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/660).

If you really want to use any object as parameter, you have to implement your own custom `FormHttpMessageConverter` which will handle that by using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

DayS is right. An as quotation, you must include the FormHttpMessageConverter in your Rest Interface definition inside the converters array:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://api.yourapp.com", converters = {
                MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class,
                StringHttpMessageConverter.class, FormHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface YourAppApiClient {

    @Post("/items/addItem.php")
    void getCustomerInformation(MultiValueMap formfields);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-**Totaly Agree** with above answers but for use of **mappinjacksonhttpmessageconverter** you have to add **another library** so if you dnt want to use it you can use below example

- Or you can consider it **as another example** also :)

`@Rest(rootUrl = CommonUtils.BASE_URL, converters =   {` `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.class,`
            `FormHttpMessageConverter.class, StringHttpMessageConverter.class` `})`

```
    public interface CustomRest extends RestClientErrorHandling{

    @Post(CommonUtils.pUrlLogin)
    String _Login(MultiValueMap<String, Object> multiValueMap);

    @Post(CommonUtils.pUrlSignUp)
    String _SignUp(MultiValueMap<String, Object> multiValueMap);
```

}